# _TypeError (type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'FutureOr<String>')

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, dart-null-safety

I am trying to fetch profile image from firestore. But it is giving an error.
Here is the code of fuction which is use to get the image from database. Kindly help if you can

```
Future<String> getUserImage() async {
  final uid = auth.currentUser?.uid;
  final users = await firestore
     .collection("app")
     .doc("user")
     .collection("driver")
     .doc(uid)
     .get();
  return users.data()?['dp'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `getUserImage` method cant return null, you can return default value   `return users.get('dp')?? "got null";`

or accept nullable data

```dart
Future<String?> getUserImage() async {
  final uid = auth.currentUser?.uid;
  final users = await firestore
     .collection("app")
     .doc("user")
     .collection("driver")
     .doc(uid)
     .get();
  return users.get('dp');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
Future<String> getUserImage() async {
  final String uid = auth.currentUser!.uid;
  final DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> users = await firestore
      .collection("app")
      .doc("user")
      .collection("driver")
      .doc(uid)
      .get();
  return users.get('dp');
}
```